# HtmlElement.SetAttribute doesn't apply to webBrowser

Tags: c#, html, setattribute

I don't get, why the changes to any HtmlElement do not change the webBrowsers display.

This is my code:

```
    private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            return;
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
            return;

        HtmlElementCollection elemCol = webBrowser.Document.All;
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser.Document.All)
        {
            if (elem.TagName.Equals("SPAN"))
                elem.SetAttribute("width", "100");  //style="background: red;"

            HtmlElement parentElem = elem.Parent;
        }
        webBrowser.Update();
        webBrowser.Refresh();
    }
```

When debugging I had a look at the OuterHtml of the element - this changes as expected.
When looking at its parent element's innerHtml it changes as well.
Even the body innerHtml of the webBrowser.Document changes.
However it has no influence on the webBrowser in Gui. Having a look at the source code there you cannot find the changes.

Any idea? I still tried Update() and Refresh() but with no success.

Comment: What language is this? You should [edit] in the proper language tags.

Comment: Sorry for that. I use C# with WinForms

Answer (score 0):

I use this to change `Style` attributes

```
var currentStyle = htmlElement.Style;
htmlElement.Style = currentStyle.Replace("margin-left: 450px", "margin-left: 50px");
```